# numpy.median of empty array now yields error in version 1.10.0

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

We just recently updated from numpy 1.9.3 to 1.10.0 and I started getting error messages.

In numpy 1.9.3, `np.median(np.array([]))` produces a NaN (and a warning about taking a mean of empty slice).

The same code in 1.10.0 now produces an `IndexError`, with a traceback to

```
in _median(a, axis, out, overwrite_input)
-> 3138         n = np.isnan(part[..., -1])

IndexError: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Is this the intended use case now? I found on the [release notes](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/release/1.10.0-notes.rst) mentions of the `nanmedian` function, and indeed running `np.nanmedian(np.array([]))` produces the expected NaN and empty slice warning from previously.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly earlier bug/issue about the median of an empty array

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6197

Someone will probably cross reference your new bug/issue to this.